# Nesting Parent-Child Relationship Query

Tags: soql, custom-object, query, account, relationships

In my data structure I have a several custom objects that form a relationship to the Standard Salesforce Account Object.

I have three custom objects:

- `L_Account`
- `L_Contact`
- `L_Enrollment`

`L_Enrollment` -> `L_Contact` -> `L_Account` -> `Standard SF Account`

I want to get a Count per Standard SF Account for how many L_Enrollment exist that match a creation date (on the L_Enrollment level)

Can this be done? I am familiar with [SOQL Relationships](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/05/basic-soql-relationship-queries.html) but need a great amount of help on the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with aggregate queries. Making some assumptions about the `API Names` of your relationship fields:

```
Map<Id, Integer> accountIdToEnrollmentCount = new Map<Id, Integer>();
for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
    SELECT count(Id) records, L_Contact__r.L_Account__r.Account__c accountId
    FROM L_Enrollment__c WHERE CreatedDate = :2016-10-21
    GROUP BY L_Contact__r.L_Account__r.Account__c
])
    accountIdToEnrollmentCount.put(
        (Id)aggregate.get('accountId'),
        (Integer)aggregate.get('records')
    );
```

---

**What's going on here?**

The map itself is fairly straightforward. Let's break down the query:

- You can `GROUP BY` a specific field (even many relationships distant).

  - When you perform queries using this clause, they return `List<AggregateResult>`.
- When you use this clause, each field must be grouped or aggregated.

  - With the relationship to `Account` you group it by including it in the `GROUP BY` clause.
  - With `Id` you count the number of populated values, which gives you the total number of enrollments you are looking for.
- When you use this clause, you can alias any field in your `SELECT` clause, which can make your code a lot more concise and easier to wrap your head around!

  - Here we can now just call `aggregate.get('accountId')` even though the relationship is really `L_Contact__r.L_Account__r.Account__c`.
  - We can also get the count in an easy to understand way. Without aliasing, you would have to use `aggregate.get('expr0')`, which is ugly and doesn't scale very well.
- Note that when working with `AggregateResult`, you have to use the `SObject.get` method, which returns an un-cast `Object`. That's why you have to cast the results (`(Id)`, `(Integer)`).

Comment: Thanks Adrian, the logic makes sense. I swapped in my actual field names into the query successfully. To display the Map, will I need to create a VisualForce Page? I am less experienced with this, could you point me to some resources on building the remaining components to get this to display in a dashboard?

Comment: You will need `Visualforce`, yes. I'd recommend taking a look at this [Visualforce Cheatsheet](http://developerforce.s3.amazonaws.com/books/Visualforce-cheatsheet.pdf), playing around with it a bit, and asking more questions on here if you get stuck. :)